# Typewriter append with fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello I'm trying to make typewriter with `fadeIn` effect but my method doesn't work. Could you tell me how can I add `fadeIn` effect to this script?

```html
<div class="inner container">
    <h2>Typewriter test</h2>
</div>
```

```js
var title = $('.inner h2').html();
$('.inner h2').html('');
var arrayTitle = title.split('');
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (i > arrayTitle.length) {
        $('.inner h2').html(title);
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        //$('arrayTitle[i]').hide().appendTo('.inner h2').fadeIn();
        $('.inner h2').append(arrayTitle[i]).fadeIn(50);
        i++;
    }
}, 50);
```

Comment: +1 for the cute little display effect... Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `fadeIn` individual characters like that - your `fadeIn()` call is applied to the whole header, which is already visible.  If you add each character as a `<span>`, you can fade *that* in:

```
var header = $('.inner h2');

var title = header.text();
header.text('');        

var arrayTitle = title.split('');
var i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  if (i > arrayTitle.length) 
  {
    header.text(title);        // wipe out the <span> tags
    clearInterval(interval);
  } 
  else
  {
    $('<span>')
      .text(arrayTitle[i])
      .appendTo(header)
      .hide()
      .fadeIn(50);

    i++;      
  }
}, 50);
```

Example, with longer intervals to show the fade-in more clearly: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/ixBdm